Flutter TextField onTopOutside: can not refocus after unfocus
      Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Example')),
          body: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 40,
            child: Builder(builder: (context) {
              return TextField(onTapOutside: (event) {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              });
            }),
          ))

onTapOutside: lose focus on tap outside. but
the TextField could not regain focus when tapping the text field.

Works fine for me... Perhaps some other widget is interfering on your stack.

 class _ExamplePageState extends State<ExamplePage> {   final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Listen to focus changes to handle unfocus logic properly
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        print('TextField lost focus');
      }
    });   }

  @override   void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const                   Text('Example')),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // Unfocus the TextField when    tapping outside of it
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 40,
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Tap me',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );   } }

